# BeautifulSoup: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

EDIT: I added the full set of code since my attempt at simplifying it didn't work. I was able to comment out the problematic line and it works, so I assumed I was ok until then

I'm working on a web scraper and I'm stuck on this AttributeError on this line `historical_seasons = soup_loop.find('select', {'name': 'comp_id'}).contents` and can't figure out what is wrong

```
# https://statbunker.com/robots.txt

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# navigate to https://rugby.statbunker.com/
url = 'https://rugby.statbunker.com/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# create lists of all leagues
league_links = []
leagues = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'pointer'})

for link in leagues:
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        league_links.append(link['href'])
print(league_links)

# create list of all seasons for that league
season_links = []
for link in league_links:
    response_loop = requests.get(link)
    html_loop = response_loop.content
    soup_loop = BeautifulSoup(html_loop, 'html.parser')
    
    league_results = soup_loop.find_all('img', alt='Latest Results')

    for results in league_results:
        parent = results.parent
        if parent.has_attr('href'):
            season_links.append(parent['href'])

    # historical seasons
    historical_seasons = soup_loop.find('select', {'name': 'comp_id'}).contents

    for season in historical_seasons[3:-1]:
        season_id = season['value']
        base_url = 'https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/LastMatches?comp_id='
        new_url = base_url + season_id
        season_links.append(new_url)
print(len(season_links))
```

What's particularly confusing for me is that when I isolate it somewhat it seems to work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# navigate to https://rugby.statbunker.com/

url = 'https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/LastMatches?comp_id=637'
response = requests.get(url)
html_loop = response.content
soup_loop = BeautifulSoup(html_loop, 'html.parser')

test_list = []
historical_seasons = soup_loop.find('select', {'name': 'comp_id'}).contents

for season in historical_seasons[3:-1]:
    season_id = season['value']
    base_url = 'https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/LastMatches?comp_id='
    new_url = base_url + season_id
    test_list.append(new_url)
print(test_list)
```

Comment: Your first entry in `league_links` is missing an opening `'` character, is that the problem? That should just give you a SyntaxError, though...

Comment: If I fix that error, the program builds fine for me with Python 3.9, and prints `63` at the end.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem. First snippet, after fixing the typo, works fine for me. it prints 63

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for taking a look, I just updated it to be my full code, thought I could just isolate the area with the error

Comment: @buran thanks for taking a look, I just updated it to be my full code, thought I could just isolate the area with the error

Comment: If you print `link` in each iteration you will see that the 4th link is `https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/LeagueTable?comp_id=` and as a result you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full code finally recreated the error for me. Looking through the output of `print(league_links)`, the fourth one is `'https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/LeagueTable?comp_id='`, with no `comp_id`. This loads a page with no table, therefore there's nothing to be found with `soup_loop.find('select', {'name': 'comp_id'})`, so it returns `None`. `None` doesn't have an attribute `content`, hence your error.

I'm not sure why the `comp_id=` link is being returned, so you'll have to debug that part yourself.